# Is it possible to store session in simple JavaScript function and then access that session attribute in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session

i am trying to store the value of selected radio button in session storage  in JavaScript.And later i want that value to be used in angularjs function .Is it possible.If yes then please help me

Comment: yes it is possible to access to access session storage value but you need to use different module like "ngStorage" refer link http://ngmodules.org/modules/ngStorage

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make use of localStorage of the browser

```
window.localStorage - stores data with no expiration date
code.sessionStorage - stores data for one session (data is lost when the tab is closed)

// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

In AngularJS, you can make use of [Angular-local-storage](https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U4t9E/)

Comment: i want to store session value without creating a controller.and then i need to use that session value in another controller in angularjs

Comment: the session value will be created in angular scope?

Comment: then you can set an Item with a key in javascript. As the localStorage object is of the browser, the key can be accessed in the angularjs controller

Comment: @codeghost added the fiddle in the example.. see that in the first few lines I have added 'test' key value of 'Hello World'

Comment: i am very new to fiddle .can u tell me how to browse your code ?

Comment: the js part would be in the left bottom window....over there I added only three lines first to check if window.localStorage is a property for the browser, and if yes then set window.localStorage with key of 'test' as then in the controller the test key is used to set get localStorage via a textbox

Comment: i tried your code .but u are adding the textbox inside controller.I want in plain textbox without any container .

Comment: The textbox is in html, and using ng-model for the textbox. this ng-model will update a scope variable in the controller. I think that only is your requirement in the question